# How to start Ubuntu Desktop from CLI?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I'm using a Macbook Pro M1, and trying to set up an Ubuntu VM using UTM.  I've managed to set up Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Server, but am having issues getting the Desktop / GUI part running.

I've followed this guide to the letter - https://mac.getutm.app/gallery/ubuntu-20-04 - and managed to get the server installed fine.

At the end of the guide, I'm told to do the following to install Ubuntu Desktop:-

```
$ sudo apt install tasksel
$ sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
$ sudo reboot
```

That had no effect.

I then found another guide here - https://linuxconfig.org/start-gui-from-command-line-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa - which says to run the following:-

```
$ sudo systemctl isolate graphical
$ sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Again - zero effect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, running the following a second time, was enough to resolve the issue:-

```
$ sudo apt install tasksel
$ sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
$ sudo reboot
```